# Move div to top while scrolling and stay there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could I make my div move to the top of a page while scrolling as it does by default, but then once it reaches the top of the page, stay there? I have seen this done on other pages, and my guess is that it might not be able to be done with CSS alone, but might need jQuery and JavaScript as well. I would prefer using just CSS, but using jQuery and JavaScript is an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this snippet below:

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
p {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Made for my post: <a href="http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html">Stick div at top after scrolling</a>.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque,
  lectus in pharetra blandit, augue mauris pulvinar erat, ut euismod nibh
  lectus sed diam. Nulla fringilla ultrices ligula. Aliquam vitae felis metus.
  Maecenas lacinia bibendum accumsan. Curabitur lobortis convallis purus
  non imperdiet. Morbi ut vulputate mauris. Curabitur lacinia faucibus volutpat.
  Nulla elit tortor, rhoncus ut luctus eget, blandit in risus. Integer accumsan
  ullamcorper lorem id porttitor. Aliquam vitae libero eget magna mollis
  gravida.</p>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
  tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
  justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
  arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
  orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
  morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
  sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
  neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
  mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
  quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
  accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
  ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
  Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
  Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
  molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
  porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
  nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
  Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
  tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
  velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
  imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
  Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
  id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
  ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
  Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
  enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
  tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
  justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
  arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
  orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
  morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
  sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
  neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
  mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
  quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
  accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
  ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
  Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
  Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
  molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
  porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
  nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
  Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
  tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
  velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
  imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
  Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
  id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
  ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
  Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
  enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
  tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
  justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
  arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
  orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
  morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
  sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
  neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
  mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
  quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
  accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
  ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
  Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
  Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
  molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
  porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
  nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
  Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
  tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
  velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
  imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
  Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
  id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
  ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
  Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
  enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
```

Tutorial: http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, just had to wait a few minutes before it allowed me to. When I implement your example, my page jumps a bit when hitting the div. I also noticed this in your example on jsfiddle, and I was wondering if there is any way to "fix" this.

Comment: @Choops are you talking about the black part at the top of the text that gets hidden when scrolled to the top?

Comment: No. When I scroll down and the top of my webpage hits the div, the webpage "jumps" down about 25-50 pixels. It might, however, just be Google Chrome. I'll try testing it in a different browser.

Comment: @Choops Yeah, it works perfectly if Firefox. Also, if you [checkout the demo in the tutorial](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html), that works perfectly in Chrome as well!

Comment: Strange! Maybe my mac is just being weird. I tried the demo and the same thing is happening. Could you see if my site is working for you? It is the "Recent Donators" div on the right side causing me this trouble. http://csgobets.acoxi.com

Comment: It's happening in all my other browsers as well, so I'm pretty sure it might be a mac issue. Could you check my site to see if it is, though, because at the moment the jumping is very distracting.

Comment: @Choops Your site is working pretty smoothly on my Windows machine, on both Firefox ans chrome. You may post another question for this issue.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for that. I'll try and see why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this..

```
position:fixed;top:0px;
```

Comment: No. This will keep my div in the same spot at all times, but I want my div to move upwards until it reaches the top of the page, and then the div will stay there.

Comment: oh okk.. am sorry.. i thought u r asking for that... I don't know how to do it.. sorry..